# SQL query to retrieve the matching data over secondary tables link to master tables

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server database with 4 tables.

1st table contains the list of names with a primary key:

```
id1    Name
---------------    
 1     ABC
 2     XYZ
```

2nd table is having foreign key to 1st table with related properties.

```
id2   Properties   id1
-----------------------
 1      P1          1
 2      P2          1
 3      P3          1
 4      P2          2
 5      P3          2
 6      P5          2
```

3rd table contains some tasks:

```
id3    task
-----------
 1     T1
 2     T2
```

4th table task properties is related to task table with foreign key:

```
Id4   Properties   id3
-----------------------
 1    P1            1
 2    P2            1
 3    P3            1
 4    P2            2
 5    P3            2
 6    P5            2
```

Scenario in my case is that I have Task and I have to match its properties with 1st table name's properties.

e.g.  on task 2, properties will be matched with XYZ.

I was trying with group by and having count but no luck to get accurate result.

Is anyone can please help me out for it?

Comment: Why do you have different tables for a task and its properties? Is there a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Have you looked at `JOIN`s?

Comment: Yes there is One to many relationship. I tried it using joins but it will not work as expected as I have to match the properties. What i want to achieve is to match properties of task with each name' properties and If all task properties are present in name' properties then include that name into result. If I go for some front end (.Net), I have to use nested loop to match the properties but it will be not quicker way to do it. I am looking for a way to do it in SQL.